# Using submithandler (Jquery Validate ) to submit a form upon validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, submit, validation

Ive been having a hard time using the "submit handler" part of the jquery validate function.

My code for that is as follows ($ms for a noconflict call):

```
    submitHandler: function(a2) {
        $ms("#HID_Join2").val("J2");
        $ms("#submit_button").hide();
        $ms("#submit_loading").show();
        a2.submit();
    }
```

but I keep seeing in firebug that 
**"a2.submit is not a function"**

Here is how I call the form, if it matters.

```
<form id="billingForm" name="billingForm" method="post" action="joinSEM2.asp"> 
stuff stuff stuff
</form>
```

the first three steps are executed, but the form does not submit. Ive tried using the .submit and .post functions instead, but I cant get them to work in conjunction with validate. 
Any suggestions? something Obvious I am doing wrong? I have used this before with no problem, so i dont know why this is happening... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case try:
$("#billingForm").submit();